# Can't retrieve database instance from Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, collections

For some reason, I could not retrieve data from firebase database. Please have a look at my code and rules. Thank you

my code

```
List<EvaluatingImage> imageInfo = [];

  Future<Query> queryUsers() async {
    // DatabaseReference referenceData =
    //     FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('pictures');
    DatabaseReference referenceData =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');
    referenceData.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataSnapShot.value;
      values.forEach(
        (key, value) {
          print(value['email']);
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      //allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 9, 28);
      allow read, write : if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Instead I got this error

```
W/SyncTree(29984): Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
E/flutter (29984): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseError(-3, Permission denied, )
E/flutter (29984):
```

Please help me! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The above rules are for firestore while you are using firebase realtime database, you need to change the rules for the realtime database to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**Note:** The above rules will enable all users to read and write from the database, only use the above rules for development

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: But this is for firebase real-time database and I'm using cloud_firebase

Comment: the code that you are using is for  `DatabaseReference referenceData =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()` realtime database.. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database